# Не работает драг-дроп, либо дублируются items в recyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, adapter

В приложкнии реализован драг-дроп на ресайслере, в нем же находятся 2 вьюхи разного типа(проще говоря первый тип превьюхи видео, второй - кнопки), второй тип дублирует себя вместо какой то другой превьюхи, хотя в массиве айтемов находится верный тип. это решается в адаптере ресайслера

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

этот же подход не дает нормально работать драгдропу, который работает только с кодом

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return 0;
}
```

драгдроп работает через ItemTouchHelper

что делать?

Comment: так принято задавать вопросы "на раене конкретным пацанам", здесь все же таки более культурное место... переформулируйте вопрос и уточните что не получается в *приложухе* :)

Comment: @Barmaley ну я так понимаю, что и тут сидят не "пацанчики с раена" и они вполне могут понять, что такое drag'n'drop на элементе RecyclerView. Писалось пока в голове мысли летали в облаке данной проблемы. переформулирую чуть позже

Comment: Ну вот, как мысль уляжется и переформулируете - приходите снова. Будем рады